# If the patent is granted, will be granted and if not why?

Tags: legal-status, abandoned-patent

In reference to the patent: [US 2012/0138076 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20120138076)

Has this patent been granted? Please can I have as much information on this patent as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary source of information is the [USPTO Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) database which has a CAPTCHA and does not allow direct links to individual patents. On that site, Search for Application by Publication Number "US 20120138076 A1". The Image File Wrapper contains a large number of documents, but of particular note is an Abandonment on October 22, 2014. The reasons for abandonment will be in that publication, which is freely available. Also available is all of the correspondence between the examiner and the inventor. Only under very rare circumstances may an abandoned patent be revived.

See also the [USPTO Assignment Database](http://assignment.uspto.gov/#/search?q=20120138076).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response really appreciate it. Sorry to ask another question just trying to make sure I understand. So that patent was rejected? As far as anyone using that idea is that ok? Because they are all products that have already been invented? Basically could I go on to manufacture a similar product and it would be ok and nothing no one could do? Again really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance. Jake.

Comment: In the image file wrapper it says oath or declaration does that mean they have sold the patent? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: ? Can anyone help. Thanks.